# Can't print without brackets

Tags: python, arrays, list

```python
import random
n=[random.randint(10,999) for i in range(int(input()))]

print(n,end=', ')
```

The problem is I need it to print without squared brackets. How can I change my code by not over complicating it.

Here is what it prints out:

> `[385, 396, 37, 835, 376]`,

and it needs to look like this

> `305, 396, 37, 835, 376`

I have tried putting brackets in multiple places also I have tried deleting things and all that happens is it prints the same thing or there is error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the ints to strings and use `join`:

```
>>> n = [385, 396, 37, 835, 376]
>>> print(", ".join(map(str, n)))
385, 396, 37, 835, 376
```

Another option is to use the `*` operator to spread `n` as multiple arguments to `print`:

```
>>> print(*n, sep=", ")
385, 396, 37, 835, 376
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> n = [385, 396, 37, 835, 376]
>>> print(str(n)[1:-1])

385, 396, 37, 835, 376
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a list of integers. You can convert them to strings and use the `string.join` method to get the format you want.

```
import random
n=[random.randint(10,999) for i in range(int(input()))]

print(", ".join(str(val) for val in n),end=', ')
```

(Note: `map` is an odd thing to use in a language that already has native mapping constructs. Best to keep it native).

Comment: no matter whether I use a generator expression or `map` in an answer like this, someone always goes out of their way to complain that it wasn't the other one.  I just flip a coin each time now.  :)

Comment: Why even construct a list when you can just use an iterator?
`n=(random.randint(10,999) for i in range(int(input())))`

Comment: @md2perpe - Yes, you can do that too. My answer is focused on the display part. Given a list, how to print. In fact, it would work with many types of sequences or generators. For this exact script, your suggestion is very good.

Comment: @Samwise - true, but... map/filter/reduce are functional programming concepts. Although you can do functional programming with python, its not built that way top to bottom. Other functional programming tools are in `functools` and map/filter/reduce should be there also. Comprehensions are the "built in" way to do this. map's existance in `builtins` is a fluke.

Comment: Why the `end=','`? It will add an extra comma at the end...

Comment: @Tomerikoo - yes, it replaces the newline normally written... but that's what the original code does too. I don't know the poster's intent with that so I just left it. You could ask the author what the intent was.